SQL select statement that creates a new column for each item in a specific column
Sorry for my poor English and poor question.
I got below table in SQL DB.

and my goal is below result.

I would like to write a select statement so that each item in the ID column forms a new column. X, Y coordinate information is shared.
So I tried some groupby statements and ChatGPT, But I failed all.
test code is below.
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as db
from random import randint

# create original df
data = {"ID":"ID1", "X":[1,2,3], "Y":[3,2,1], "VAL":[randint(0, 100) for x in range(3)]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
data = {"ID":"ID2", "X":[1,2,3], "Y":[3,2,1], "VAL":[randint(0, 100) for x in range(3)]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
data = {"ID":"ID3", "X":[1,2,3], "Y":[3,2,1], "VAL":[randint(0, 100) for x in range(3)]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)


# make df to db
conn = db.connect(":memory:")
df.to_sql("test", conn)
cur = conn.cursor()

# extract from db
cur.execute("select * from test") # 
cur.fetchall()



You should research PIVOT

give me a minute. I will seartch PIVOT. thank you

Original problem is in the Oracle DB, But I made simple psudo problem for asking in python SQLite3 DB. and this is problem. SQLite3 doesn't surport PIVOT. (https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) So I cannot test PIVOT statement now. BTW, thank you Randy. I'll do it later.

Try this
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT ID, X,Y, VAL
FROM table) AS SourceTable PIVOT (
SUM(VAL)
FOR ID IN ([ID1],[ID2],[ID3])) AS PivotTable 
ORDER BY 1 ASC;


thank you for your answer but currently I cannot test it. I'll do it later.
